# MSDeploy task and presync

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, web-deployment, msbuild-task

Is it possible to specify preSync/postSync commands via MSDeploy task? If not, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of MSDeploy task are you using? If it's through Exec of msdeploy.exe then yes, of course, if it's some kind of a wrapper that doesn't support them directly then you can emulate those by calling sync again with run-command provider since pre/post-sync is just another call to sync within try/catch/finally structure wrapping main sync anyway.

```cs
private int ExecuteWorker()
{
    ...
    if (!this.HandleAuxillarySync("-preSync", this._commandLine._preSyncParameters, retbaseOptions2))
        return -1;
    DeploymentChangeSummary deploymentChangeSummary;
    try
    {
        deploymentChangeSummary = @object.SyncTo(retproviderOptions2, retbaseOptions2, syncOptions);
    }
    ...
    finally
    {
        this.HandleAuxillarySync("-postSync", this._commandLine._postSyncParameters, retbaseOptions2);
    }
    this.HandleAuxillarySync("-postSyncOnSuccess", this._commandLine._postSyncOnSuccessParameters, retbaseOptions2);
    ...

private bool HandleAuxillarySync(string syncType, Dictionary<string, string> sourceParameters, DeploymentBaseOptions destBaseOptions)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        using (DeploymentObject @object = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(retproviderOptions, retbaseOptions))
        @object.SyncTo(destBaseOptions, syncOptions);
            flag = true;
    }
```

Comment: I am using MSBuild task MSDeploy from Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets.

Comment: In that case no, just call separate syncs conditionally pre and post your main sync just like the exe itself does.